# Can I ask if another answer is still relevant?

Tags: discussion

I was recently looking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable) question when I noticed that all the top answers there are from 2008! That is back in early Java 6 days. I would like to know if that answer is still applicable. Would such a question be on topic for StackOverflow?

Comment: Note that the accepted answer was edited in 2014, so were some other ones. Instead of asking the question, I would do the research myself. The accepted answer provides links to the javadoc for Java 7. For Java 8 javadoc, just replace the 7 with an 8 in the links. For that specific question, I see no reason to ask if it still applies as you have all the tools available to find out on your own.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yeah, I noticed that as well. My question is meant in general though, not in this specific case. There are plenty of Q and As that haven't been updated since foreverago.

Comment: In general, if the existing information is outdated or about an old version of the tech, feel free to ask a question about the *new* version, linking to the old one if it provides context. That said, just asking "Is this still applicable" isn't a great question, because you can do the research yourself as was already noted.

Comment: I would personally hope if you simply asked "Is this still relevant?" that your question would be marked and closed as a duplicate (or closed for some other reason).  This really is minimum effort... please put some effort in on your own to determine to the best of your ability whether or not its still applicable, *then* if you find it isn't, either ask a question about the new way to do this (if you can't figure it out), or perhaps better yet, post an updated answer to the old question (if you do figure it out).

Answer (score 1):

Please do not ask a new question about an old question's answer and only ask "is this still relevant".

If you have done testing and things, and weren't able to get it to work, then go ahead and ask a new question showing your code and you can also comment that you tried doing what this answer said, but can't get it to work.

At this point people can then answer whether it is a problem with doing it this old way and you should do it this new way now, or they can find out what you were doing wrong for why it wasn't working.